# Debugging the Mining Process

Tags: mining

I'm looking to use a debugger on my macOS to step through the process of mining. It would me better understand the programatic process of what the miners are doing.

I have a single small GPU on my mac. I tried building ethminer from the source and running in Xcode but my GPU doesn't have enough memory.

Does anyone know if I can somehow use a smaller DAG or is there another simple tool to help me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Start a local development chain

The easiest way to do this is to create a small local development chain that only you are participating in.

That way you'll be guaranteed to mine the blocks, and you won't have to GPU mine to participate.

## Upgrade your GPU

The other thing you could do is to get an external GPU (google eGPU) for mining and connect it to Thunderbolt / USB-C.